# Executar um método com a aplicação fechada "Service"

Tags: ios, swift, thread, services, background

No Android é possível enviar notificações, fazer consultas via http, executar métodos, tudo através de um Service sem que o usúario precise necessáriamente rodar a aplicação, só  o fato do service estar ativo, tudo acontece naturalmente. Vejo que no iOS não há esse conceito de Services.

Como eu faço para executar um simples método (de tempos em tempos) sem que o usuário tenha que abrir a aplicação manualmente, ou seja um conceito de "Service".

Comment: Olá, qual a real necessidade de um `service` rodando? Como mencionei na outra pergunta, background no iOS é bem limitado. Se você está construindo uma app a partir de uma código/app feito para Android que faz uso intenso desta *feature* você terá grandes problemas se não tentar reestruturar sua arquitetura para as limitações do iOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depende do que você quer dizer com "tempos em tempos".

De fato no iOS não tem toda essa liberdade que existe no Android. Existem os [Background Modes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) (veja a tabela 3-1), cada um para uma necessidade específica. Acredito que o mais próximo que você precise é o `fetch`:

> The app regularly downloads and processes small amounts of content
>   from the network.

O que acontece neste caso é que ao implementar o *delegate* [`application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:), o **próprio iOS** decide qual a periodicidade de execução desta tarefa, baseada em cada aparelho, utilização, disponibilidade de rede e outros fatores, então você terá cerca de **30 segundos** (veja na discussão do link) para fazer tudo o que quer até que o aplicativo seja terminado novamente.

Enfim, acredito que o máximo que você consegue chegar é nisto.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, então com isso consigo executar uma requisição http por exemplo sem que o usuário de fato esteja na aplicação?

Comment: Exatamente, lembrando da limitação dos 30 segundos para se concluir todo o processo e da periodicidade, que não existe uma maneira de definir, é um algoritmo do próprio sistema, para cada tipo de usuário.