# Como obter dados em um web service ao receber uma push notifications com aplicação em estado inativo

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notification, push-notification

Tenho uma aplicação que ao receber uma push notification precisa se conectar ao meu web service para obter dados relevantes para o usuário.

Quando o estado do aplicativo está ativo ou em segundo plano ele consegue fazer essa conexão, mas se o aplicativo está com o seu estado inativo a conexão com o servidor não acontece.

Como devo manipular a notificação quando o estado do aplicativo é inativo para realizar essa conexão?

Comment: Mas por que você não envia já de uma vez os dados necessários junto com a notificação? São muitos dados? Em *background*, a única forma de fazer download de algo é através de *Background Modes*, eu [respondi uma questão](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/69717/4337) sobre isso, veja se clareia algo pra você.

Comment: @PauloRodrigues, O problema de enviar os dados junto com a notificação é a garantia de entrega. Da forma que é feito hoje sempre que chega uma notificação eu faço a requisição de todos os dados que tenham o id maior do que o que eu tenho armazenado na aplicação. Esse Background Modes pode ser uma paliativo, porem não seria a solução ideal, pois iria fazer requisições em momentos desnecessários.

Comment: Mas a garantia de entrega é em relação à notificação, sem ela, dá na mesma se os dados vão junto ou depois que for recebida, não?

Comment: @PauloRodrigues, sim a garantia é em relação a notificação, da forma que esta hoje, se eu deixar de receber uma notificação, quando eu receber a próxima eu terei todos os dados atualizados, pois sempre verifico o id da aplicação com o id do servidor, pegando assim tudo que ocorreu desde a ultima notificação. Em resumo a notificação só serve mesmo para avisar que tenho dados para buscar no servidor.